How to get build number with empty code repository
In our group, test team is trying to use the "Test Plan" in DevOps. Developers are not using DevOps. So there is no code and no pipeline.
When we execute a test case, we would like to put the build number of the application. But looks like the build number can only be generated by the pipeline. Is that right? Is there a way to manually create the build number?
Or, is it possible to create a dummy pipeline just to generate the build number?
Thank you.
I tried to create a pipeline, but it need a project and code in the Github. My empty Github account doesn't work.
